# Interfacez graficas C++

Tags: c++

No me permite usar la librería `glui.h` como puedo solucionarlo?

> ..\GRAFICOS\GLUI\include\glui.h|54|fatal error: GL/glut.h: No such
>   file or directory|

Comment: El error está claro: no existe ese archivo.